# Get a DriveItem resource from shared folder by path

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

all.

I have a problem to get DriveItem by a path from OneDrive service.

The first request: **GET me/drive/root/children**

```
      "remoteItem": {
    "id": "EF8A24CC458790DF!106",
    "parentReference": {
      "driveId": "ef8a24cc458790df",
      "driveType": "personal"
    }
  }
```

The second request: **drives/ef8a24cc458790df/items/EF8A24CC458790DF!106/children**

```
{  "value": [
{
  "parentReference": {
    "driveId": "ef8a24cc458790df",
    "driveType": "personal",
    "id": "EF8A24CC458790DF!106",
    "name": "src",
    "path": "/drives/ef8a24cc458790df/root:/onedriveapi/src"
  },
} ] }
```

But request: **/drives/ef8a24cc458790df/root:/onedriveapi/src** failed with code "itemNotFound".

This has to work:
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/blob/live/docs/rest-api/api/driveitem_get.md

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I have tried it. It works. Could you provide more information for your case. I suggest you should check your 'driveId' for your request

Comment: @kikang, What information do you need? If I share to you my folder, can you give me the path to the file?

Comment: I don't need you to share the folder, because that's your information and it will violate the rules. What I need to confirm is whether you passed the correct 'DriveID' in your request. So I suggest that you provide details of these two requests without carrying personal information.

Answer (score 0):

It is bug in API.
For non-owner cases, a direct path from the root is not allowed. 
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/908